# No Module named loglevels

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-18.04, odoo-10

I'am learning `Linux Ubuntu 18.4 Odoo 10` by following this [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04/#configure-ufw-firewall-for-odoo) and [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html). But upon after setting up to my pycharm I encounter this error `Module Not Found Error : No module named 'loglevels'`. Earlier I got an error also `no module named ..` But I already fixed it. This time even I use the command `pip3 install config` or `pip install config` the error still there. BTW I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Can you share the python code you have? I guess you're importing logslevel at some point but it's not install, you should do a ```pip install logslevel```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `loglevel` library.

> pip install loglevel

[PyPi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/loglevel/)